# date conversion from DD-MM-YYYY to yyyymm

Tags: sql, oracle11g

Below is the query i tried but iam getting error. Please correct me.

select to_char(to_date(01-03-2018, 'DD-MM-YYYY'), 'yyyymm') from dual;

Getting below exception

```
ORA-01847: day of month must be between 1 and last day of month
01847. 00000 -  "day of month must be between 1 and last day of month"
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
select to_char(to_date('01-03-2018', 'DD-MM-YYYY'), 'yyyymm') from dual;
```

The first argument of TO_DATE function should be from the char group so you need to use quotes.

Answer (score 2):

You missed quotes around date. That's why Oracle treats 
01-03-2018 as a number and evaluates it to 1-3-2018 = -2020  and then tries to treat -2020 as the day number of the current month since no other date elements appear to be present.
Real query that oracle execute behind yours is:

```
select to_char(to_date(to_char(1-3-2018), 'DD-MM-YYYY'), 'yyyymm') from dual;
```

And the correct query is

```
select to_char(to_date('01-03-2018', 'DD-MM-YYYY'), 'yyyymm') from dual;
```

Thanks to @Alex Poole who corrected this explanation.

Comment: It's missing quotes, not parentheses. It's treating `01-03-2018` as a numeric expression, which evaluates to `-2020`; it then tries to use that as the day number for the current month since no other date elements appear to be present.

Comment: @Alex Poole Sorry for my English. Of course I meant quotes. And you are right, it treats it as number. Thanks - I've learned something new today. I'll correct this answer with your explanation